# How to show ccs grid guides overlay with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do I display the css grid guides, I want to color each column with an overlay color, I saw the source here https://github.com/UseAllFive/css-grid-guides

how to use in plain HTML/CSS/JS

Show grid guide overlay like this

[image: 1]

this is my code :

```
.grid-12 {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to learn css grid, I recommend that you use mozilla firefox because in the devtools there is a grid, which can display grid lines that can help in learning grids

[image: this is pict]

or you can see my repo, i use css grid
[css grid](https://github.com/arsyaadi/simple-landing-page)